# Retrieving all logged in session data using a common column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, fetch

Working on this for 2 months and thought I would finally ask a question. I have 2 tables:

table 1:(teacher registration)
code    teacher
1       Smith
2       Allen

table 2:(student registration)
code    student     stdpassword
1        Jan            abc78 
2        Cindy          jhni 
1        Peter          e99bd
1        Bobby          h2y1e
1        Marsha         huhu1

This is what I want the teacher with code 1 to see in the retrieved data on the webpage:

studentname   studentpassword
Bobby            h2y1e
Jan              abc78
Marsha           huhu1
peter            e99bd

I would like the teacher to retrieve all their student names and passwords using the code during the teachers session. This is what I have so far. Any help is welcomed.

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentregistration WHERE code = $_SESSION[code]");
$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die ('error getting data');

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['stdname'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['stdpassword'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    }
```

echo "";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Remove `mysql_query` from `select` query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM studentregistration WHERE code = '".$_SESSION[code]."' " ; 
$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql) or die ('error getting data');
```

instead of

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentregistration WHERE code = $_SESSION[code]"); 
      ......^
$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die ('error getting data');
```

Comment: I'm getting 2 errors with the new $sql = line. 1)Notice: Use of undefined constant code - assumed 'code' 

2) Notice: Undefined index: code

Comment: the reason for either missing `session_start()` in top of the page or $_SESSION[code] is not set!

Comment: Add `session_start();` top of your file

Comment: session_start(); was there. Where/how do I set $_SESSION[code]?

Comment: set `$_SESSION[code]` is nothing like you need to assign code value to `$_SESSION[code]` . make sure you have assigned the value and also to check session values use the `print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: I have changed the code to the below. No errors but nothing is being retrieved.             $_SESSION['code'] = 'code';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM studentregistration WHERE code = '".$_SESSION['code']."' ";
$query = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql) or die ('error getting data');

Comment: copy the query and check in your mysql query window and check whether table has data

Comment: print_r($_SESSION); is returning Array ( [user] => 31 [code] => code )

Comment: `[code] => code` is it correct? what is your table code column contains?

Comment: The code column contains numbers. the user number is correct.

Comment: Then your `$_SESSION['code']` value aslo need the number right? rather than `code` string as you printed in session array

Comment: I'm still having trouble because not understanding the responses. It comes with being a novice. Thanks for your time.